# how can i fix attribute error in python pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

[image]

I got an attribute error in pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey so as its written in your error message, you have written pygame.display.set.caption('fist game')
that is close enough for first try, so congrats !
but you need to know "set" itself is not an attribute itself
the actual code is, if you want to keep on uing this structure of code :
pygame.display.set_caption('first game')
see that _ ? yea the actual att is set_caption so yea, just a tiny mistake.
hope i helped ! :D